# Sorting li's in jQuery loaded divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting

I make a 3 language website, where I need to sort the comments from all the 3 languages, that they are visible on every language's pages. http://www.polinapasztircsak.com/guestbook/
I tried loading with jQuery `.load` method, and it works, but the problem is that it loads the separate languages in `div`s (I didn't know other way to load and append it) and I can't sort the comment `li`s outside their `div`s. Here is the code:

```
var commEng = $('<div></div>').load('../guestbook/ .comment');
var commHun = $('<div></div>').load('../vendegkonyv/?lang=hu .comment');
var commIta = $('<div></div>').load('../libro-ospiti/?lang=it .comment');

$(".commentlist").empty().append(commEng).append(commHun).append(commIta);
```

Do you have some other suggestion how I could load in the `li`s, that I have them together in the same `ul`, and then which method or plug-in to use for sorting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `$.get` or any other ajax functions to load the comments, then sort them using Javascript's `sort` function. The code would look something like this:

```
var loaded = 0, 
    sites = 3,
    comments = []; 

function getComments(url){
    $.get(url, function(data){
        comments[loaded++] = ($(data).find('.comment'));
        if(loaded === sites){
            var insert = comments[0];

            for(var i = 1; i < comments.length; i++){
                insert = insert.add(comments[i]);
            }

            $('.commentlist').append(insert.sort(function(a, b){
                var dateA = new Date($.trim($(a).find('.comment-meta:first a').text()).replace('at', '') + ' GMT'), 
                    dateB = new Date($.trim($(b).find('.comment-meta:first a').text()).replace('at', '') + ' GMT');

                return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
            }));
        }
    });
}

getComments('../guestbook/'); 
getComments('../vendegkonyv/?lang=hu');
getComments('../libro-ospiti/?lang=it');
```

This will sort the jQuery element received through ajax with `sort()` by passing in a function that will compare the dates of the comments scraped from the comment meta. Also remember that `div`s in `ul` unordered list is not valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much it works great! The only thing I had to add was the empty() before append(), so that the old comments get removed, before the newly sorted comments are placed in.
Best Regards,